# How to Backup Automatically Mysql in C# coding?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to backup my Database in MySQL for Each time Application is Closing.

I googled for the DUMP in MySQL. but i got only php or batch file programs.

Any one know how to Backup Automatically Mysql in C# coding?.

Or Executing Batch is the Only way. Is it possible in Winform C#?.

**My Connection String is -**

```
connectionString="server=192.168.1.100;User Id=root;database=mcs_sps;Persist Security Info=True"
```

Thanks in Advance!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are good samples and a good best practice in the following link: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?47,214274,214274#msg-214274

I think your best shot is that aL3891 suggests unless you do not want to pay . If you want to pay for this simple task check out these links:

1. http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDump.html
2. http://www.devart.com/

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class you can start an instance of [Mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) or [Mysqlhotcopy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlhotcopy.html), command-line programs for dumping an entire mysql database.

Comment: Simple and reliable.  Can't lose with that.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256466/MySqlBackup-NET-MySQL-Backup-Solution-for-Csharp-V

I tried it in my application and it works perfectly